# How do I list subdirectories in Windows using C++? I need solution using windows API alone

Tags: c++, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I just came across this link,This Program will print the directories alone.How can implement a code within this program that will display all the subdirectories also ? Can u please give the solution in the form of code  .

```
 #include <windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <strsafe.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

    void DisplayErrorBox(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

    int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
    {
       WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
       LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
       TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
       size_t length_of_arg;
       HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
       DWORD dwError=0;

       // If the directory is not specified as a command-line argument,
       // print usage.

       if(argc != 2)
       {
          _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
          return (-1);
       }

       // Check that the input path plus 3 is not longer than MAX_PATH.
       // Three characters are for the "\*" plus NULL appended below.

       StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

       if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 3))
       {
          _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
          return (-1);
       }

       _tprintf(TEXT("\nTarget directory is %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

       // Prepare string for use with FindFile functions.  First, copy the
       // string to a buffer, then append '\*' to the directory name.

       StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
       StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

       // Find the first file in the directory.

       hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

       if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
       {
          DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
          return dwError;
       } 

       // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

       do
       {
          if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          {
             _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
          }
          else
          {
             filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
             filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
             _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
          }
       }
       while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

       dwError = GetLastError();
       if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
       {
          DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
       }

       FindClose(hFind);
       return dwError;
    }


    void DisplayErrorBox(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
    { 
        // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
        DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dw,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL );

        // Display the error message and clean up

        lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
            LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
            TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
            lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    }
```

Comment: This is c not c++. For c++ have a look at `std::tr2::sys`.

Comment: Recursion..............

Answer (score 0):

A quick working hack of the sample below (needs additional command line argument -r). Works till path exceeds MAX_PATH. Replace the main in sample with these two functions. Note the check to NOT recurse "." and "..". That is never ending :) You dont have to rename _tmain , but then there is no where to put a breakpoint to pause at the end.

```
int modified_main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
   LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
   TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
   TCHAR szSubDir[MAX_PATH];// 260 bytes
   TCHAR* temp_argv[3];
   size_t length_of_arg;
   HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   DWORD dwError=0;
   BOOL recursive = FALSE;
   // If the directory is not specified as a command-line argument,
   // print usage.

   if(argc < 2)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
      return (-1);
   }

   if( (argc > 2) && 
       (('-' == argv[2][0]) && 
        ('r' == argv[2][1])) )
   {
      recursive = TRUE;
   }
   // Check that the input path plus 3 is not longer than MAX_PATH.
   // Three characters are for the "\*" plus NULL appended below.

   StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

   if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 3))
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
      return (-1);
   }

   _tprintf(TEXT("\nBegin directory : %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

   // Prepare string for use with FindFile functions.  First, copy the
   // string to a buffer, then append '\*' to the directory name.

   StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
   StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));


   // Find the first file in the directory.

   hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

   if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
   {
      DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
      return dwError;
   } 

   // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

   do
   {
      if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
      {
         _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);

         if((recursive) && (ffd.cFileName[0]!='.'))
         {
            _sntprintf(szSubDir,MAX_PATH,_T("%s\\%s"),argv[1],ffd.cFileName);
            temp_argv[0]=argv[0];
            temp_argv[1]=szSubDir;/* new dir*/
            temp_argv[2]=_T("-r");
            modified_main(3,temp_argv);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
         filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
         _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
      }
   }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);



   dwError = GetLastError();
   if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
   {
      DisplayErrorBox(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
   }

   FindClose(hFind);

   _tprintf(TEXT("\End directory : %s\n\n"), argv[1]);
   return dwError;
}




int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   return modified_main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code rakeshdn.But this prog too print only folders inside a directory.I tried and put it in both recursive and iterative way.Thanks again..:)